# Bootstrap 3 Horizontal Divider (not in a dropdown)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know **`Bootstrap 3`** has a horizontal divider you can place inside of dropdown menus to separate links like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
   ...
  <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
</ul>
```

**My question is:** Is there any way to do this without it being in a dropdown, such as putting it into any kind of list or similar menu?

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Yes there is, you can simply put `<hr>` in your code where you want it, I already use it in one of my admin panel side bar.

Comment: `<hr />` is even better.

Comment: @ErwinMayer `<hr />` is for XHTML. In HTML 4 or 5 it's just `<hr>`

Comment: It's an old reply, but for those who stumbled on here like i do, <hr> should not be used for presentation purpose like in OP case. It is for thematic change in paragraphs. Just like one should not use P tag to format controls.

Answer (score 17):

Currently it only works for the `.dropdown-menu`:

```css
.dropdown-menu .divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

If you want it for other use, in your own css, following the *bootstrap.css* create another one:

```css
.divider {
  height: 1px;
  width:100%;
  display:block; /* for use on default inline elements like span */
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As I found the default Bootstrap `<hr/>` size unsightly, here's some simple HTML and CSS to balance out the element visually:

**HTML:**

`<hr class="half-rule"/>`

**CSS:**

```
.half-rule { 
    margin-left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 50%;
 }
```